# LEFT JOIN on multiple tables in "FROM" part

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-columns

I'm unable to find an exact example on stackoverflow, so here is my problem. In MySQL 4.x it works fine, but 5.x seems not to like the following:

```
SELECT some stuff..    
FROM schools, member , applications
LEFT JOIN courses ON courses.id = applications.course_id 
LEFT JOIN staff ON staff.id=member.staff_id
```

This section throws up an error saying "Unknown column 'member.staff_id' in 'on clause'". How do I change this so that 5.x won't complain?

EDIT: I did notice that when using 'ONE' LEFT JOIN, it did matter where the table name was placed in the FROM part, ie it has to be at the end. Not sure this has any relevance to the problem though. This is only an issue with 5.x

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have the same database schema between the two versions you're testing?

Comment: Yes, it's is exactly the same. I've noticed this issue with other clients' programs I've written before (all using MySQL 5.0>)

Comment: is that the entirety of your query? or have you left there `where` clause out?

Comment: There is a where clause as well, but it's not relivent to the problem. It only has a few restriction added to the schools table.

Comment: This is where I would usually remove parts of the query until the error went away to narrow it down. It is a little weird that you're mixing the old and new-style join syntax but I don't think that is supposed to be a problem.

Comment: where only filters the schools table? nothing on member or applications? you're aware this is cross joining? rewriting the query to use explicit join syntax only, and not mixing in implicit joins will get rid of your error, as `joins` have higher precedence than the `,`, so they are resolved first. hence, member table does not exist when the `join` is performed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official MySQL doco, the precedence of the `join` operator is higher than that of the `,` (comma) operator. This will cause your `joins` to be evaluated without the `member` table, meaning `member` is not available in the `join`.  However because the `applications` table is the last in your series of comma delineated tables, it IS available to the joins. MySQL effectively sees the tables like this: `(schools, member, (applications left join courses ... ))`

[13.2.8.2 JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur.

The reason you are encountering this error now, whereas you were able to do it before, is (from the same link)

> Previously, the comma operator (,) and JOIN both had the same precedence.

To get around this order of operations limitation, you can either rewrite your query using explicit join syntax only, or you can force the grouping of your comma separated tables by surrounding them with parenthesis, which will make MySQL see your tables more like this `( (schools, member, applications) left join courses ... )`

```
SELECT some stuff..    
FROM (schools, member , applications)
LEFT JOIN courses ON courses.id = applications.course_id 
LEFT JOIN staff ON staff.id=member.staff_id
```

But i'd still recommend using explicit join syntax.

```
select some stuff..
  from schools
    join member
    join applications
    left join courses on courses.id = applications.course_id
    left join staff on staff.id = member.staff_id
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Any reason why using explicit joins is better than adding parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Your edit helped. MySQL doesn't seem to like like that you are mixing the old-style comma separated join syntax with the newer ANSI SQL-92 join syntax.

I would rewrite it as

```
SELECT some stuff..    
FROM schools
  JOIN member ON (...)
  JOIN applications ON (...)
  LEFT JOIN courses ON courses.id = applications.course_id 
  LEFT JOIN staff ON staff.id=member.staff_id
```

You will probably have to move some conditions up from your WHERE clause.